# How do I hot reload a module wrapped in a native import context?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I have the following function a file `@/lang/index.js`:

```js
async function fetchMessages(locale) {
  const module = await import(/*
    webpackChunkName: "lang/[request]",
    webpackExclude: /index/
  */ `@/lang/${locale}`)

  return module.default
}
```

I would like to hot-reload the modules imported by this function. I've tried a several different variations of `module.hot.accept()` but without success.

Here's my hot reload code at the end of the same file that doesn't work:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept(["./en-US"], () => {
    const { locale } = i18n
    fetchMessages(locale).then((strings) => {
      i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, strings)
    })
  })
}
```

Any thoughts? I would like to hot-reload my language files when a change is detected.

Thanks!

Comment: I tracked down the root of the problem to `index.js` not being the direct parent to `en-US.js`. For each `import()` expression a new "module" is created.

If I use Webpack's internal identifier for that module (`"./src/lang lazy recursive ^\\.\\/.*$ exclude: index"`) then it will work but the compiler will try to resolve that string to a module and throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack currently has an open issue for this "bug". I found [Webpack#8637](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8637) after some searching.

Some workarounds from that page include:

- Create a separate file which contains the import context, accept that separate file.
- Use `module.hot.accept(module.children[0].id, ...)`

The solution I'm currently using is I found the generated identifier for the context, and saved it to a variable is passed in to `module.hot.accept()` like so:

```js
const asyncChunkId = "./src/lang lazy recursive ^\\.\\/.*$ exclude: index"
module.hot.accept(asyncChunkId, () => { /* ... */ })
```

It's rather fragile, but does the job for now.